# Validate Certificate using Python

Tags: python, openssl, ssl-certificate

I want to access a web service over HTTPS.

I have been given a client certificate (p12 file) in order to access it.
Previously we were using basic authentication.

Using python I am unsure how to access it.

I want to use httplib2

```
h = Http()
#h.add_credentials("testuser", "testpass")
#h.add_certificate(keyfile, certfile, '')
resp, content = h.request("https://example.com/webservice", "POST", xml_data)
print content
```

Now, I am quite new to SSL, Can I just call add_cert or somethign similar and give it the p12 file.
Do I need to convert it to a PEM file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question was IN my question

```
h.add_certificate(keyfile, certfile, '')
```

I had a pkcs12 file, I just needed to extract out the key and cert from the p12 file.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -out key.pem -nodes -nocerts
openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes -nokeys
```